# Deleting a file with name that already exists in Trash

Tags: files

I use `delete-by-moving-to-trash` to move deleted files and folders into trash instead of deleting them. However, if the file or folder with the same name is already in Trash I get an error `file already exists"`.

On macOS and while I delete file using Finder which name already exists in the Trash it adds current timestamp to the deleted file name to differentiate it. For example `foo` become `foo 20.28.19`.

Is there a way achieve the same in Emacs?

That would solve the problem, but I'm also open for other solutions if they exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Finder to move the files with the following function

```
(defun system-move-file-to-trash (filename)
  "Move file or directory named FILENAME to the trash."
    (ns-do-applescript
     (format
      "tell application \"Finder\" to delete POSIX file \"%s\""
      filename)))
```

Not tested on recent Mac OS versions.